# Connecting PC to video converter with HDMI

Tags: windows-8, graphics-card, hdmi, desktop-computer, amd-catalyst

I have purchased a device to convert the HDMI output coming from my PC and connect it to a older TV. I want to use it as a second display, mainly for videos. The device does not register to my video card as a valid display so it is not showing up. I have a PC with a Saphire ATI Radeon HD video card and am running the latest Catalyst control center software and drivers. The OS is Windows 8.

I have tried setting common resolutions to see if it would work, but noting is showing up. The converter is supposed to show all had formats from 720p to 1080p and it is supposed to show 1:1 scale.

I have tries starting the computer with only the single device plugged in but still noting.

However, for a split second while the BIOS image is showing on PC start, the picture works, which tells me that the device works, but the PC is not outputting the content that its expecting.

Any Ideas?

Comment: What type of adapter is it and what kind of cable connects to the TV?

Comment: @ekaj - It's a EnjoyGadgets HDMI to VGA converter (Found here: http://www.amazon.ca/dp/B008MPB9YQ/ ) I connect it to my pc with HDMI and connect it to tv with component (YPbPr)